# Regular Expression - How to find the <%@ %> line in the file?

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I found there is a bug in this highlight editor: http://cshe.ds4a.com/

The following ASP.Net code can't be highlighted correctly

```
<%@ Page Title="<%$ Resources: XXX %>" Language="C#" ContentType="text/html" ResponseEncoding="utf-8" %>
```

The problem is about the regular expression, how can I find this whole line by regular expression?

I am using the RegExp from ActionScript3

The main challenges are:

1. The **<%@ %>** instruction may contains another **<%$ %>** instruction in its attribute, just like the one above
2. The **<%@ %>** instruction may have a line break in it, just like the following.

```
<%@ Page Title="<%$ Resources: XXX %>"
Language="C#" ContentType="text/html" ResponseEncoding="utf-8"
 %>
```

3
. The <%@ %> instruction may followed by another **<%@ %>** without any space / line-break

```
<%@ Page Title="<%$ Resources: XXX %>"
Language="C#" ContentType="text/html" ResponseEncoding="utf-8"
 %><%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
```

Thank you

Comment: What language are you using? RegEx flavors behave differently and have different features, so knowing this will help. Please edit and tag the question with the language you are using.

Comment: This is a classic example of where RegExs fall down - they're not designed to handle nested expressions like this.  Really you'd need a proper ASP.Net parser to do this properly.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Can you try and post the original regex? Otherwise this is just guess work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
/<%@[^%"']++(?:(?:%(?!>)|"[^"]*+"|'[^']*+')[^%"']++)*+%>/
```

Anything that's enclosed in double-quotes or single-quotes is treated as generic string content, so a `%>` in an attribute value won't prematurely close the tag for matching purposes.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure all these escapes are necessary, but I kept them for good meassure. This found your line in notepad++ find

```
^<\%\@.*\%>$
```

EDIT

For multiple lines, set the multiline and dotall flags. Those inform that the expression should span over several lines, and that the . wildcard should match newline (\n).

```
/<\%\@.*\%>/sm
```

or

```
<\%\@.*\%>
```

With s and m flags.

Comment: Thanks, but actually this line can have a line-break in it, just like <%@ Page Title="<%$ Resources: XXX %>" 
Language="C#" ContentType="text/html" ResponseEncoding="utf-8" %><%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>, I don't think your expression will works :)

Comment: Then you have to set the multi line flag. Depending on your software, usually that's done by adding "n" behind the end delimiter.

Comment: That is not just about multi-line switch, I am using thr RegExp from ActionScript3, The <%@ %> instruction may contain line break;  The instruction attribute may contain another <%$ %>, and <%@ %> may followed by another <%@ %> without any space / line-break

Comment: Then you should consider trying a programmatical solution, using more than one regex if necessary.

Comment: @Codemonkey: The multiline flag is irrelevant; all it does is change the behavior of the `^` and `$` anchors, which aren't being used here.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the headline I created a little RegEx which also takes care of whitepasce at the start or end of the file. However I can not assure if this fits into your project.

```
^\s*<%@.*>\s*$
```

I tested this with the PHP function `preg_match_all()`

Update:

Use this pattern for a across multiple lines. Your RegExLibrary has to support the parameter "s" (which accepts newlines as character) though

```
/\s*<%@.*>\s*/s
```